# Symbolic dynamics in continue dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems

Do you know a good and studied example of symbolic dynamics applied to a continue dynamical system? I mean, if there is an example of a continue dynamical system for which there is a Poincaré map for which there is an invariant set conjugated to the space of $N$ symbols with the shift operator.
And, if there is, one or more books where i can find it.

Comment: Great starting point: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485890097

Comment: Thank you, but this is too much difficult for me (I mean, objects used in that paper, like for example Fuchsian groups, which i have never heard about, doesn't allow me to read and understand this without before reading lot of literature concerning other field of mathematics and other definitions). I found the "strange attractor" in the Lorenz system can be what i was looking for; in Robert Devaney, Morris W. Hirsch - "Differential equations, dynamical systems, and an introduction to chaos" it seems that it's explained with basic calculus facts and without any new definition. Thanks anyway

Comment: I understand, I didn't know your background. A minor word of caution, if I may: the Lorenz system has associated a hyperbolic system with singularities, which is not really what you want, at least from your question. This corresponds to the fact that in Figure 14.10 in that book (by Hirsch, Smale and Devaney) the two parts of the graph are not onto. Without exaggeration, this makes the situation atypical from the usual one, and you may be studying a different thing from what you want to study.

Comment: yes i know, it's not exactly what I wanted, but the chaotic nature was the main thing i was looking for, not necessary with cantor sets or symbolic dynamics. Maybe I express myself a little wrong before. Thanks a lot for the advice, have a nice day:)